# Send Puppeteer Generated Pdf to another microservice using requestPromise npm

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer, form-data, request-promise

I have two microservices: 1) in which I am generating pdf using Puppeteer, which is essentially a Buffer object. From this service I want to send the pdf to another microservice, 2) which receives the pdf in request and attaches it in email using mailgun (once I am able to send pdf from one service to another, attaching as an email wont be difficult).
The way I m sending the pdf in requestpromise is this:

```
import requestPromise from "request-promise";
import {Readable} from "stream";

//pdfBuffer is result of 'await page.pdf({format: "a4"});' (Puppeteer method).

const stream = Readable.from(pdfBuffer); 
/*also tried DUPLEX and Readable.from(pdfBuffer.toString()) and this code too.
   const readable = new Readable();
   readable._read = () => {}
   readable.push(pdf);
   readable.push(null);
*/

requestPromise({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${anotherServiceUrl}`,
        body: {data},
        formData: {
            media: {
                value: stream,
                options: {
                    filename: "file.pdf",
                    knownLength: pdfBuffer.length,
                    contentType: "application/pdf"
                }
            }
        },
        json: true
    }
});
```

But doing so, I get "ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END" error. How can I send this pdf from one service to another, since the other service sends the email to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(pdfBuffer).toString("base64").toString();
```

sending the buffer in the `body`.

---

On Receiving service:

```
const pdf = Buffer.from(body.buffer, "base64");
fs.write("file.pdf", pdf, ()=> {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it from the frontend with:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
  },
  body: pdfData
}
```

In this case pdfData is a blob so you would need a polyfill for that plus node-fetch

Comment: I know how to do it using the frontend but wasn't able to solve it between two backend services. However, I did it by converting Buffer to base64 and then to string and sending in the body. Converting the received string to base64 and then to Buffer and saving the buffer to file or sending as an attachment.